# Routes for users and admins separation Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I'm trying to separate user from admin and forbid access of user to admin section.

My directories structure is

```
resources/
  -views/
    --site/
      ---users/
      ---admin/
```

In `web.php` I've added this

```
Route::get ('/', ['uses' => 'HomeController@index']);

Route::auth();
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth'], 'namespace' => 'users', 'prefix' => 'site/users'], function() {

   // users routes
});

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth'], 'namespace' => 'admin', 'prefix' => 'site/admin'], function() {

   // admin routes
   Route::get ('/admin', ['uses' => 'AdminController@index', 'before' => 'admin']);
});
```

When I log as admin and tried to open http://example.com/admin I've got

> (1/1) NotFoundHttpException

Same happens with users.

I have column in database `is_admin` which I check and store in session during log in.

Comment: I think this will help 'site/admin' => 'admin' Route::get ('/admin' => Route::get ('/'

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand you.

Comment: Try this: Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth'], 'namespace' => 'admin', 'prefix' => 'admin'], function() {

   // admin routes
   Route::get ('/', ['uses' => 'AdminController@index', 'before' => 'admin']);
});

Comment: Thanks @Bas, this is really works!

Comment: What if I have other directories too which I want to access as user? How add multiple dirs in `prefix`? Like this `Route::get ('/cart/order', ['uses' => 'CartController@order', 'before' => 'auth|csrf']);` This route I can access now

Comment: And user still accessing admin dashboard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is to create for example `AdminMiddleware` in `App\Http\Middleware`.

```
php artisan make:middleware AdminMiddleware
```

The put inside newly created middleware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($request->user()->type != 'A')
    {
        return redirect('home');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Based on you comment in the question that you store your user session and you check column `is_admin` you need to change the check in the `if()`. If you use `Auth` would be something like this

```
if (Auth::user()->is_admin != 1) {...}
```

or whatever you have in `is_admin` column. Then in your routes you access it like this

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'App\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware'], function()
{
    Route::get ('/admin', ['uses' => 'AdminController@index', 'before' => 'admin']); 

});
```

[Source](https://laravel.io/forum/02-17-2015-laravel-5-routes-restricting-based-on-user-type).

Comment: Thank's for the answer. Will try it in a min.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can try this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth'], 'namespace' => 'admin', 'prefix' => 'admin'], function() { 
  // admin routes 
  Route::get ('/', ['uses' => 'AdminController@index', 'before' => 'admin']); 
});
```

Hope this work for you !!!

Comment: It is working at least to load the pages. But `user` still can access admin part

Comment: When I check the user `dd(BaseController::isAdmin())` I've got `false` so should not be able to access `admin` section, right?

Comment: @Peter what are you trying to achieve? domain.com/admin and domain.com/users?

Comment: Simply restriction of users to access admin part